# command CHOICE in DOS batch replacement/reproduction in python

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to reproduce the behavior of the command CHOICE in DOS batch but with python.

raw_input requires the user to type whatever then press the ENTER/RETURN key. What I really want is for the user to press a single key and the script to continue from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Unix, it uses sys, tty, termios modules.

```
import sys, tty, termios
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

For Windows, it uses msvcrt module.

```
import msvcrt
ch = msvcrt.getch()
```

[Source](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/915)

Answer (score 2):

A small utility class to read single characters from standard input : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892-getch-like-unbuffered-character-reading-from-stdin/